# Rails - See generated SQL queries in Log files

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

Is there a way to see all generated queries from rails in production environment like you can in development?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can. If you go in the config/environments/production.rb file, there's a section like this:

```
# See everything in the log (default is :info)
# config.log_level = :debug
```

Uncomment the config.log_level line, and you'll get the same log in production as you would in dev.