# Log every SQL query to database in Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, logging

This question is a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629351/log-every-sql-query-to-database-in-rails), where should I place this code?

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
class << connection
  alias :original_exec :execute
  def execute(sql, *name)
    # try to log sql command but ignore any errors that occur in this block
    # we log before executing, in case the execution raises an error
    begin
        file = File.open(RAILS_ROOT + "/log/sql.txt",'a'){|f| f.puts Time.now.to_s+": "+sql}
    rescue Exception => e
      ;
    end
    # execute original statement
    original_exec(sql, *name)
  end
end
```

I have tried placing it inside of the model, but what happens is when I execute some sql query more then once it returns "**stack level is to deep**" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in config/initializers. Most likely it's because of reloading classes each time in dev env. This code need to be executed only once though.