# How to shorten/suppress the "get column attributes" query in the log file when using PostgreSQL with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Rails likes to get column attributes for each table you're using. On MySQL this was as simple as (if I recall) something like `DESCRIBE mytable`, which fit nicely into one line in the log.

But with PostgreSQL, it's more involved and turns out to be the following:

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"mytable"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
```

The trouble is that this takes up a heck of a lot of lines in the development log and makes it somewhat harder to peruse.

So I'm wondering if there's a good way to suppress or summarize the logging of this sort of query in particular.

I feel like this is such a privileged firstworldproblem, but it's been slightly troublesome for a while.

Comment: Try some custom code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4333165/382818. Also look at the link to the question in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `silent-postgres` gem.

You can do this in Rails 3 by adding `gem "silent-postgres"` to your `Gemfile`