# to_sql not working on update_attributes or .save

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a way to store the sql string that is generated in an update or create action. I've tried appending `.to_sql` to the end of `update_attributes` but it returns a `TrueClass` error (or something like that). Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I dont think that possible because I dont thing since arel was never meant for update/delete logic correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Why are you trying to store the SQL in the database?

Comment: So I can reference it later as an API endpoint to return all the queries ran between "x" dates to then have those queries run on a mobile app which uses sqlite (the main DB is mysql). Basically a way to sync the mobile app with whats in the mysql db.

Comment: You might have issues trying to feed MySQL SQL to SQLite.

Comment: Maybe, but the queries would be pretty basic - insert, update, and delete. Nothing too fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods both return a boolean. You can't invoke `to_sql` on a boolean.

Comment: That's what I figured. Is there any way I can capture the sql that is executed? Obviously it gets output in the log file, but I'm looking to store the string in the database at the time of execution.

Answer (score 3):

> In brief - you need to override ActiveRecord execute method. There you
>   can add any logic for logging.

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
class << connection
  alias :original_exec :execute
  def execute(sql, *name)
    # try to log sql command but ignore any errors that occur in this block
    # we log before executing, in case the execution raises an error
    begin
        file = File.open(RAILS_ROOT + "/log/sql.txt",'a'){|f| f.puts Time.now.to_s+": "+sql}
    rescue Exception => e
      ;
    end
    # execute original statement
    original_exec(sql, *name)
  end
end
```

credits:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1629474/643500

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1640560/643500

Comment: Like the guy said on the original post, where would you put this at?

Comment: You can put it anywhere you like, really. Personally, I think an initializer for it makes sense, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Assuming I put it in the initializer, how would I "call" it so that I can log the query? The above code, to me, implies this will run every time. I'm looking to have such a method run on certain actions in many controllers.

Comment: Yes, that function will capture every query.  You will have to filter it down to the class\method you want to log.  This is the closest to get to the rails generated queries.  If you just want to handle some methods, you can take a look at the log and write a custom method that will generate the sql string to perform the same operation.  Wont be simple.  Therefore, capturing the generated rails queries from active record, filter the object/method then finally saving the data is the easiest and guarantees to match the generated queries.