# Can I see what SQL an ActiveRecord .save call would generate, without doing the save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For an ActiveRecord query, I can see the SQL generated without actually executing it:

```
SomeModel.where(something: "something").to_sql
```

No query was sent to the DB, but I can see the SQL as a string.

Is there anything similar that can be done for the `update` SQL that will be generated by `some_model.save`?

I think maybe not, I can't find it!

Answer (score 3):

@jrochkind, If we check the API for `.save` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save) then it just calls `create_or_update` [method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/create_or_update). So ideally, such methods returning boolean values will not generate queries using `to_sql`.

Also, I think similar topic is covered here [to_sql not working on update_attributes or .save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037475/to-sql-not-working-on-update-attributes-or-save?lq=1)

And probably there is an alternate approach such as to [override ActiveRecord execute method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13038222/840272)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Even I have not seen any method to generate sql for `save` yet.</strike>

I also faced a situation earlier and I found that we can use the `sandbox` mode of `rails console` to verify the queries and it will be rollback the changes made in the session once we close the console.

`rails console --sandbox`

[documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console)

> If you wish to test out some code without changing any data, you can do that by invoking rails console --sandbox.

`@Rohan Daxini` have added the reason why `.to_sql` is not available on `save`

Comment: So this solution would involve getting the SQL from the logs, right?

Comment: Yes @MarlinPierce

Answer (score -2):

Do save within a transaction with a rollback at the end
eg.

```
irb(main):024:0> Post.transaction do
irb(main):025:1* p=Post.create(user_id: User.first.id, text: '11', group_id: 1)
irb(main):026:1> raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
irb(main):027:1> end
```

Comment: How do you get the SQL out of this? You have to grep the logs?

Comment: That actually might the solution for my situation.  Yes it would be scraping the logs.