# Ruby on Rails SQL Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Is it possible in **Ruby on Rails** to log only the **SQL commands** generated and save it on a separate file?

I'm still in development mode and looking to save all the SQL commands on a seperate log.

I've checked the development.log files but they also save data like the

`"Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-17 16:41:47 +0800, etc.`

I am looking to either create a separate log file only for SQL or remove these other lines leaving only the SQL commands.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629351/log-every-sql-query-to-database-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use active record, you can overwrite the active record logger :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/sql_log.log")
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that. Can you give specifics on where I would need to add this line?

Comment: Oh, I added it to the development.rb and it works! thank you Intrepidd!

Comment: Regarding the sql logging, It appears the SQL log was transferred to the sql_log.log but how do you include for example the 

'Started GET "/controller/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-17 08:50:45 +0800
Connecting to database specified by database.yml'

which is just before the SQL commands because this would include the  date and time the SQL commands where executed.

Comment: I suggest you create your own logger class (make it inherit from Logger) and override the ``add`` method to include the time. More info : http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-add